# Add Resources Include Directories to VS2015 projects with CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm building wireshark with Visual Studio 2015. After CMake finishes I need to manually add `$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);` to the `Resources -> Additional Include Directories` of multiple projects in the solution. Adding the folders to the general `Additional Include Directories` of a project doesn't work, Only if I add to the `Resources` Includes it works. How do I get CMake to Add directories there?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set(CMAKE_RC_FLAGS "${CMAKE_RC_FLAGS} /i<path>")`

If your code only works with Resource Include Directories, it must rely on the Windows Resource Compiler (`rc` on command line). So, adding the include directory to your CMAKE_RC_FLAGS settings, the equivalent of adding it as an `/i` option to `rc`, should fix it.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.